# What is faster? Bitwise operations or Array operations. Why?

Tags: arrays, performance, bit-manipulation, programming-languages

Assume there is a row of 10 bulbs. Their state can either be ON (1) or OFF(0).

This could be represented by an array.

```
states = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Or as a 10 bit number.

```
states = 1011010010
```

**Updating states** (setting a value in the list):

For the array it would be

```
states[0] = 1
```

For the bits it would be using a bit mask

```
states = states | 10000000
```

Similar operations would be done for clearing bits, etc.

Which of these operations is faster? Which cases should arrays be used and likewise for bits?

I've seen that certain engines like chess/checker engines use bit strings to store board states (1 = piece on square, 0 = no piece on square). Some also use arrays. If possible this context can also be considered.

Comment: Using bitmasks should be faster, since doing operations on a simple integer is faster than doing array access arithmetics. You have to be careful that the integer type can contain all of your bits.

Comment: I +1 on @Adder comment but want to point out that anything that can be contained within a machine register will be faster. However; if the state list were to grow beyond that boundary you will need to do a fetch (may or may not be in cache) which will degrade the performance.

Comment: There is no general answer.  Using an array exercises the memory sub-system, using bits gives the processor core more work to do.  Distinct parts of the machine, the only way to be sure is to try it.

Answer (score 1):

> Which of these operations is faster?

Suppose we have `N` flags, where `N` is a big number. Let us compare what is need to be done in order to test a flag.

#### Array of flags operation:

Each `flag` is a byte, so the size of the array is `N` bytes.

```
byte states[N];
sizeof (states) == N;
```

1. Access array, i.e. `value = *(&states + index`
2. Compare `value` to zero.

#### Bit operation:

Each `flag` is a bit, every 8 bits are grouped into bytes. So the size of the array is `N / 8` bytes.

```
byte states[N / 8];
sizeof (states) == N / 8;
```

1. Calculate array index, i.e. `arr_idx = index / 8`
2. Access array element, i.e. `value = *(&states + arr_idx`
3. Calculate bit index, i.e. `bit_idx = index % 8`
4. Test if bit `bit_idx` in `value` is zero.

As we can see, bit operation will take a bit more steps. But CPUs are good at power of two operations needed for those extra steps, so from performance point of view it will be just a tad bit slower.

> Which cases should arrays be used and likewise for bits?

We will prefer bits to store a huge number of flags. Each byte has `8` bits, so memory footprint for bits will be always `8` times less than for bytes.

We will prefer bytes for simplicity, speed and atomic operations. Most CPUs have special "atomic" instructions to test/set/clear byte atomically, but not bits in byte.

For instance, if that array of lags is used between few threads in out application, we can use atomic CPU instructions to operate over that array. For bits it will be a bit more complicated, with locks or compare-exchange loops.

Comment: Why calculate array index for bits?

Comment: @hashris I mean when we have a lot of flags, i.e. when it does not fit into one `state`, so we need to keep an array of `states`. For the simplest case you described, it is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise operations on registers take (at most) one clock cycle on modern processors (x86, ARM, etc.) It's actually much more than that, since these types of operations use some of the simplest units within the CPU that are able to execute and retire multiple ops in a single cycle (e.g. Intel CPUs), so assembly programmers consider these operations to be free.

Array processing, on the other hand, requires memory loads and stores, and may exceed cache line sizes, which is a big latency hit if it's a cache miss.

There's really no comparison. Bitwise operations are free; array operations are relatively expensive.